# Socket says it is closed but it is not

Tags: java, android, sockets

I have a little problem with a Socket.
So, code is below:

```
    private class SocketThread extends Thread {

    String whatistodo;

    public SocketThread(String whatistodo) {
        this.whatistodo = whatistodo;
    }

    @Override
    public void run()  {
        try {

            Socket socket = new Socket(IP (is set), port (is set));  //  Eröffne Socket

            if(whatistodo.equals("read")) {

                Boolean isDone = false;
                InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();                
                InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);       

                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);             // In Buffer

                String msg;                                          


                while (!isDone && ((br.readLine()) != null)) {    

                    // stuff
                   System.out.println(msg);

                }

            }

            if(whatistodo.equals("close")) {

                socket.close();

                if(socket.isClosed()) {

                    finish();

                }
            }

            Log.d("Socket", String.valueOf(socket.isClosed()));



        } catch (IOException e1) {


        /*  Log.e("IOException", String.valueOf(e1));



            Looper.prepare();

            new AlertDialog.Builder(Bedienung.this)
                    .setTitle("Socketfehler")
                    .setMessage("Verbindung mit TCP fehlgeschlagen / verloren.")
                    .setPositiveButton("Ok", null)
                    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                    .show();

            Looper.loop(); */

        }



    }

}
```

I call the class **SocketThread** with the function `connectToSocket();`
There's one string parameter called "whatistodo".
The parameter can be "read" or "close"

```
        protected Boolean connectToSocket(String whatistodo) {

    Thread obj = new SocketThread(whatistodo);
    obj.start();

    return false;

}
```

The function `connectToSocket("read")` is called if there's a internet connection.
The function `connectToSocket("close")` is called by `onBackPressed`.

But after closing the socket, I'm still receiving messages.

How to solve  this?

Greetings, Baldoius

Comment: Testing `isClosed()` after you've just called `close()` is futile. It will always return true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you create your SocketThread, it creates a new socket. If "whatistodo" is set to "close", it will create a new socket and close it immediately. The thread created with "whatistodo" equal to "read" has its own socket, so it will continue running and reading from it.

You need to ensure that all of your threads share the same socket instance.

Comment: How would you do this?

Comment: Pass the Socket instance as parameter to the Thread constructor.